# Subcomponent - unable to uncheck the Add All Assets checkbox

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Can you please let me know what is wrong with my solution, because am unable to uncheck the "Add All Assets" checkbox on the Add Subcomponent.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each entity in a solution has two modes. The "All Assets" mode and the "Sub-component" mode. You can pick one mode on adding it to the solution, i.e. you cannot change it later.

However, you can just remove and re-add the entity to the solution so you can pick the mode.